# Show records per user in table widget in App Maker

Tags: user-interface, widget, report, google-app-maker

I'm almost finished with my first App Maker app (learned a lot, thanks for the help so far!). The app currently collects timestamp data when users log in and out of the work site. As the time between leaving and returning could be a few hours, and because App Maker is browser based, I originally had issues where the user was unable to complete the record and tap the Time_IN button. I solved this by moving the *Time IN* Button to a pop-up attached to the records page, so when the user came back to work they could open the record, tap *Time IN* and be on their way. Simple, right?

[image: New Time IN method]

My trouble now is that users were unable to see their own records on the *UserRecords* page, unless I made them admins, but then it grants access to the full table on not just their own, showing all records for all users. The navigation menu originally had this snippet of code which I removed:

```
(@user.roles).indexOf('Admins', 'Managers') !== -1
```

but I'm not sure if I've missed something as the issue still seems to be partly user role based? Here is an image of the datasource fields, there are only two models in this app, GatePass (as shown in the picture) & Directory (for user picker).

[image: Datasource Fields]

An export looks like this (and the idea is to get each user their own data, not the whole source table):

[image: Export data]

Also, this is what the users input page looks like now (if it helps), I managed to get the user email to autofill with `record.Email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` in the onBeforeCreate:

[image: User Entry Latest]

In a nutshell, the user should only see their records in the *UserRecords* page so they can access and complete their submission. The same is doubly true for their exports. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can either do this with a different datasource or with the same datasource using query paramateres. To help you a bit more, could you please edit your question and post a screenshot of how your model looks. I'm interested in the fields and the datasources.

Comment: Edited and updated :)

Comment: It just occurred to me to mention that my colleague, who was not admin at the time of initial testing, made multiple entries but none of them made it to the table as stored data until after I had made him an admin. I dunno why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, go to the **DATASOURCES** tab. If you have more than one datasource showing up, then it's up to you to choose the right one. Make sure to uncheck the option **Automatically load data**.

[image]

Next, go the page where the table is located. Then on the table **onAttach** event put the following:

```
var ds = widget.datasource;
if(!app.user.role.Admins){
  ds.query.filters.Email._equals = app.user.email;
}
ds.load();
```

That should do the trick. In regards to the permission issue with the admin role, make sure that the model has the proper permissions. For that, go the the model's **SECURITY**
tab and make sure to set the proper permissions.

[image]

References:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-app-data
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources

Comment: Thanks! It works! I looked over the code and understand how it flows, so learned something new here :) Really appreciate the help, will keep running with the app and try implement the smaller features like locking the editing after a full record has been entered/submitted and how to email the report from within the app (only thing stumping me there is attaching the export/sheet to the email).